# Spring AOP Logging with request ID

Tags: java, spring, logging

I want to implement logging based on Spring AOP which can help me in debugging. I want to track every request entry and exit for a WebApplication. Each of the methods within a single request needs to be tagged with a log id so that I can trace it later. What are the components and basic requirements that I would need to start with it. Or is there already a library based on that.

Comment: Which logging library are you using?

Comment: @M.Deinum its log4j that am using now.

Comment: Log4j or log4j2? And directly or are you using something like SLF4J?

Comment: @M.Deinum nah... actually application is bit old and using just log4j. and am planning to have it rewritten... so options are open.

Answer (score 0):

IMO instead of the AOP make use of [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) (*or even simpler [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html)*).

In case of logging with `Log4j` it will be best to use [NDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) (*otherwise please consult the docs for equivalent feature of logging framework used*)

The `preHandle` method of interceptor will contain the logic to populate the request id, which can be [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) or any other unique identifier, to NDC and should return `true` so as to continue with execution.

The `postHandle` / `afterCompletion` method of interceptor **should** clear the NDC else subsequent request may contain the earlier NDC content.

Logging interceptor will look something like below

```
public class LoggingHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     Object handler)
              throws Exception {
        NDC.push(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase());
        return true;
    }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response,
                   Object handler,
                   ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        NDC.clear();
    }
}
```

Do let know in comments if any issues / clarification is required.